# Not able to understand the meaning of a particular sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, american-english, british-english, sentence-meaning

"When she joined the organization, my mother was an 18-year old, fair and green-eyed plump girl with a ready laugh. Most men around her were older to her-coming from varied backgrounds, rural, poor, Dalit, Muslim. Many fell for her instantly and wanted to marry her. In fact, father would receive the proposal for her by some reticent young man, for her family background was intimidating."

I have written down the whole paragraph so that one can get the context. I'm unable to understand the meaning of the last sentence in the paragraph. Who would the receive the proposal, author's mother or father and who is this reticent young man?

Comment: It says '_Many_ [men] fell for her', so 'some young man' is whichever one of them it was on that particular occasion.

Comment: Your grandfather received proposals from men who were attracted to your mother, but cautious about the caste or cultural difference. "Older to her-coming" must mean "older than her, coming." "Young man" must mean "young men."

Comment: I can assure you that the 'father' in the last sentence is author's father not her grandfather based on other paragraphs of the article. She is talking about her parents' affair.

Comment: It does not make sense for the author’s father to be receiving proposals from other men to the woman who is the author’s mother. The only way this makes sense is if the man receiving the proposals was the author’s grandfather. But you have excluded that possibility so I find no answer.